# Show that expected Fisher information for location families is a constant function

Tags: self-study, fisher-information

We have a location family, with location parameter $\theta$, and densities defined over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ such that $p_\theta(x) = p(x-\theta)$.

I have to prove that the expected Fisher information

$J(\theta) = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{(p'(x))^2}{p(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$

implying that $J(\theta)$ is a constant function. Is it just about solving the integral? If yes, please a hint, my weak math background does not allow me to solve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Consider the change of variable $u=x-\theta$. [See also.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition)

By definition we have that

$$J(\theta) = \int \left[\dfrac{\partial \log p(x-\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right]^2 p(x-\theta)dx = \int \dfrac{ p^{\prime}(x-\theta)^2}{p(x-\theta)}dx ,$$

where $p^{\prime}(x-\theta) = \dfrac{d p(t)}{dt}\Bigg\vert_{x-\theta}$. Using the change of variable $u=x-\theta$ we obtain:

$$J(\theta) = \int \dfrac{ p^{\prime}(u)^2}{p(u)}du.$$

Comment: Mysterious downvoter: see the edit for a clarification. Non-narrow-minded people: see the content and judge yourself.